# QLocale toDate always return invalid QDate on "es" locale

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdate, qlocale

Why this code return an invalid date?

```
QLocale locale("es");
QDate date = locale.toDate("1-Jun-14", "d-MMM-yy");
```

If debug the locale variable, it is initialized correctly to locale es_ES, but doesn't return the date and `date.isValid()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but you have to put a `.` behind the month (short version).
I tried the following code:

```
QLocale locale("es");
qDebug() << locale.standaloneMonthName(6, QLocale::ShortFormat);
QDate date = locale.toDate("01-Jun.-14", "dd-MMM-yy");
qDebug() << date;
```

The output was surprisingly:

```
"Jun."
QDate("1914-06-01")
```

Locks like a bug to me and fails if i try to use it with a e.g. german locale.

**Update:** Ok, i got it. This is pretty confusing. You have to take the short name given by `locale.monthName`. This is for e.g. "jun." for ES and "Juni" for DE. This does not really make any sense. In germany the short name for "Juni" is "Jun". For spain i do not know it. This is a bug.

**Update 2**: I think i understand the system (at least for the german locale). If the full name is larger than 4 characters (e.g. "Januar") the short version is the real short form ("Jan") with a dot appended ("Jan."). If the full name is shorter than 4 characters the short form is exactly the same as the long form (e.g. "Mai"). But i do not get why a dot is appended, since for the EN locale no dot is appended.

Comment: It's very strange. If I put the locale "pt", it works well (junho in portuguesse). I think that it's a bug. I'll report it to QT.

Comment: Yeah, this dot is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened a case on QT and the response is that:

**The Unicode CLDR data for Spanish has a dot after the month names.**

It isn't a bug, it needs the dot.

More details: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39519